# Запомнить cookie по клику

Tags: jquery, cookie

Здравствуйте!
Имеется код:

```js
$(function(){
 $('#div1').delay(7000).queue(function(){
  $(this).remove();
  $('#div2').fadeIn(100).click(function(){
        $(this).remove();
  $('#div3').fadeIn(100);
      });
 }); 
});
```

Через 7 секунд div1 заменяется на div2, и при клике на div2 меняется на div3. Каким образом можно запомнить cookies при клике и если они есть, то показывать div1?

Comment: Не совсем понятна логика. Можно переключать классом `active`, блоки, после того как первый через 7 секунд поменяется. Ну а дальше, допустим в куки значение, что активный блок 3. Что дальше при загрузке страницы, что будет если нажать на блок 3 и т.д.

Comment: Это div1: http://joxi.ru/MAjbQxph49lL9A
Это div2: http://joxi.ru/Vm69LndfDJlb4r
При клике на div2 показывается модальное окно и div2 меняется на div3. Div3 идентичен div1.

Comment: ок. а в куки что?

Comment: В куки нужно записать $('#div2').fadeIn(100).click(function(){
        $(this).remove();
  $('#div3').fadeIn(100);
      });
И если пользователь кликнул по div2, то запомнить и показывать только div1(или div3, т.к. они идентичны). Только вот не пойму что делать с этим: $('#div1').delay(7000). Может использовать if и else?

Comment: Т.е. НЕ использовать код приведенный в вопросе если пользователь кликнул по div2

Comment: в куки это все не надо записывать, а использовать просто ключ и записывать, допустим "clicked" и если был клик по `#div2` то не и использовать `delay` при загрузке страницы. Напишу в ответ свою логику

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вы сказали, если #div1 такой же, как и #div3, то нам можно его не удалять, а просто прятать.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($.cookie('click') != 'clicked'){ // условие, если #div2 не кликнули и он вызывается
        $(document).delay(7000 , function () {
            $('#div1').hide();
            $('#div2').fadeIn();
        });
    }
    $('#div2').on('click', function () {
        $('#modal').show(); // наше модальное окно
        $('#div1').show();
        $('#div2').hide();
        $.cookie('click', 'clicked'); // запись в куки, что #div2 кликнули
    });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! Ваше решение работает. Добавил еще expires и всё стало как было задумано)